# Activate SharePoint Central Admin from console

Tags: windows, sharepoint

I have accidentally stopped the central administration service on a share point server and can't find a way to re-activate it?  Is there any way to do this from one of the SP command line utilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend on how it was stopped.  If it is simply the web site itself that has stopped, then you can open Administrative Tools -> IIS Manager, browse to the Sites -> Central Admin Web site, right click and pick Start.  If it doesn't start this way, look in your event logs and see if there is anything there, like a permissions or security error.

If it is stopped some other way or if you accidentally deleted the site then that will take additional steps to recover.

Comment: Yeah - Unfortunetly I believe the site got deleted somehow (kinda confused on how though) - I stoped the service via the Central Admin (clicked the wrong link on the 'Manage Services on this Server' page) but when I tried to start the website via IIS Manager it gave an error and then disappeared from the list of sites.

Comment: This link might help.  Step 2 explains the reprovisioning of the Central Admin web site: http://bytelab.blogspot.com/2008/02/move-central-administration-to-another.html.  As always, make sure your farm backups are good before doing this, just in case...